# How to get multiple product details in magento 1.7

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have custom functionality in my product page where a lot of products are displayed in a table. Now I have an array with product SKU's and loop them using foreach function to get details using codes below

```
$url  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $productSku)->getProductUrl();//get product page url of ech product
$productName = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $productSku)->getName();//get product name
$productPrice = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $productSku)->getFinalPrice();//get product price
$qtyStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId())->getQty();
```

The problem with this is, the loading time of my page is at 25 seconds. Is there any way to get all the product details of the sku's I have in my array in one call or one set of call , as I need to cut down the number of calls to improve my page loading time.

Comment: why don't you use a collection instead of loading model so many times :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a much simpler, not to mention more efficient, way of loading multiple products. You can load by collection:

```
<?php
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // You can filter by attributes if required.
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple') // You can change to configurable or bundle or grouped, etc.
    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', 11); // If you want to get products that are a certain attribute set.
?>
```

You can then use a `foreach` to cycle through each product and get their data that way:

```
<?php
foreach($products as $product) {
    echo "Name: " . $product->getName();
    echo "Price: " . $product->getPrice();
    // etc, etc
?>
```

More info on collections here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-8.html (scroll down to Model Collections).

EDIT - to filter by SKU's, you can either get the exact SKU's you want:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('in' => array('customsku-101', 'customsku-101', 'customsku-102')))
```

or you can get SKU's that begin with a certain string:

```
->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => 'customsku-%'));
```

or end with a certain string (`%` is the wildcard):

```
->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('like' => '%-customsku'));
```

Comment: The problem is I need to pass a specific set of SKU's to the product collection. Can i get that?

Comment: @prdp NOTE: for what you're trying to do, using either `addFieldToFilter()` or `addAttributeToFilter()` should work the same.

Comment: @prdp Did this answer help you? Please be sure to mark answers as correct if they help so others might find it useful in the future..

Comment: hey @david-wilkinson .I need to get from the sku's are product url, quantity, price and id . Of them Im not getting producturl, quantity and ID. This is the code im using now.$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*') 
 ->joinField(
    'qty',
    'cataloginventory/stock_item',
    'qty',
    'product_id=entity_id',
    '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
    'left'
)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("gt" => 0))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('in' => array($groupsku)));

Comment: @prdp Your original question simply asked for the best way of loading multiple product models, which has been answered... To get ID, simply use `$product->getId()` in your loop, for stock / inventory quantity: `$product->getQty()` and for product URL slug: `$product->getUrlPath() `(this gets the slug, not the whole category path too if you use that in your store).